# r.surf.area outputs are unclear (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, area, surface

For different projects in my company the area was calculated using `$area` (and sometimes `area($geometry`) in the Field Calculator. I decided to change the surface area calculation to using the r.surf.area tool. For this tool I use a 1m DEM which I project in ESP:258330 (Spain). Of course I would like to compare the previously used method with the "actual" surface area considering the relief.

The output that was generated by QGIS looks as follows:

- Null value area ignored in calculation: 882758.000000
- Plan area used in calculation: 1412706.000000
- Surface area calculation(low, high, avg):
- 582185.153133 606977.811322 594581.482228
- Current region plan area: 1415100.000000
- Estimated region Surface Area: 595589.071966

Now when I substract the *Null value area ignored in calculation* from the *current region plan area* I get the value that I calculated with `area($geometry)`. But I do not actually understand why this is.

What is the difference between
*Plan area used in calculation* and *current region plan area*?

I found the r.surf.area explanation in the manual but it is still too abstract for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nomenclature & Null values

First of all, please consider that all r.* modules are GRASS raster tools, and GRASS has slightly different nomenclatures than QGIS.

The "Region" is the area covered by the layer, so the whole rectangular extent (cells * columns * pixel area)

"Null values" are the parts where pixels have no value assigned, so "empty" or "transparent" pixels. If your raster represents the road network, all non-road areas (like buildings, fields, water bodies, etc.) would be "null".

So in a very lax pseudo-code:

`Area of the Region - Area of null pixels = Area of pixels with non-null values`

Does it make sense?

Also, the value you obtain with `area($geometry)` is probably 532342, while the `Estimated region Surface Area` is 595589. The difference is due to the fact that `r.surf.area` creates a TIN (Trinagulated Irregular Network) using each pixel's center and sums the values. In other words, it is not a count, but an estimation process, whose precision basically depends on the pixel size in comparison to the shape(s) irregularity.

For precise count, you could use instead `Raster Layer Statistics` or `Raster Layer Zonal Statistics` to use a mask raster layer.

### "Plan area used in calculation"

About the "Plan area used in calculation" vs. "Current region plan area", the [documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.surf.area.html) is not very extensive, but it says:

> r.surf.area calculates area of regular 3D triangulated points (centers of cells) in current region by adding areas of triangles. Therefore, area of a flat surface will be reported as (rows + cols -1) * (area of cell) less than area of flat region due to a half row and half column missing around the perimeter.

Therefore I would say that that:

- "Plan area used in calculation" is (rows-1 * cols-1 * pixel area)
- "Current region plan area" is the whole the "Area of the Region" (cells * columns * pixel area)

Based on this, with simple calculations I would infer that your region is 1334x1059 pixels.

Comment: thank you for your extensive answer, which already helps me to better understand the output. Still I do not understand the difference between Current region plan area and Plan area used in calculation.

Comment: Please see edited answer: does it help?

Comment: all is clear, you made my day!